# Rest Client JAVA

Tags: java, rest, client, facebook4j

I am trying to create a Java RESTful client to integrate with [facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html) (with a maven directory) but I don't even know where to start. Can you help me to create one or giving tips?

Thanks again!
Best regards,
Julio.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might want to start here, in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is highly recommended that you do your own reserach before asking something here**. People don't take well users who balantly ask questions expecting the community to do all the hard work for them. They are seen as leechers and instead of helping the community grow are a burden to it. Everytime you make a post where you don't tell the community what you tried, you can expect to be punished.

PS: I suggested an edit to your post to make it better. Hopefully you wont be downvoted so much from now on.

---

With this out of the way, I found two tutorials that I believe will help you:

- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html
- http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-restful-java-client-using-apache-httpclient-example/

The consensus here seems to be that you need third party tools, like Apache client, or some other library, but other than that I believe it is manageable.

I hope it helps and that it points you in the right direction regarding REST.

As far as facebook4j goes, I found this official example source:

- http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html

But if that is not enough, I also encourage you to read the following questions from StackOverflow:

- [Getting posts from a page using Facebook4j api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125895/getting-posts-from-a-page-using-facebook4j-api)
- [How to login to facebook using Facebook4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732282/how-to-login-to-facebook-using-facebook4j)